# Why in this case the inner function has no access to outer variable?

Tags: javascript, scope

According to this code:

```js
class Thing {
    constructor() {
        this.bar = (typeof foo !== "undefined"? foo : null); // (3)
    }

    static create() {
        var foo = arguments[0];
        return new Thing();
    }
}
```

the new `Thing` might be created in two ways: either directly with `new Thing` or with `Thing.create()`.

When it is created in the second way, a new variable `string` is declared. Theoretically, it should be visible within all the scope down to the `return` statement, but in the `Thing.constructor()` (which is called within `Thing.create()`) the `string` is not seen. And `Thing.prototype.bar` is always `null`.

Why is it so?

---

Here it *is* seen from the `inner()` function:

```
(function outer() {
    var foo = 5;

    (function inner() {
        alert(foo);
    })()
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Theoretically, it should be visible within all the scope down to the `return` statement

No.

It won't be visible to any function called within the same scope. I will be visible to any function **created** inside the same scope.

And in this example the `constructor()` function is in a higher scope than the `string` variable.

This would work:

```
class Thing {
    constructor(prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }

    static create() {
        return new Thing(arguments[0]);
    }
}
```

which, by the way, is nothing but syntactic sugar for:

```
function Thing(prop) {
    this.prop = prop;
}
Thing.create = function () {
    return new Thing(arguments[0]);
};
```

Comment: javascript outside of `use strict` mode will perform a scope lookup called [var hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) -- perhaps OP is confused, but hopefully reading about closures and hoisting will explain why the `var foo` is not present within the constructor in the call to `create()`

Comment: whoops i'm sorry you're totally correct, i was thinking of using a variable without declaring it -- but i didn't say anything about changing the functions, merely that the closure is different in the functions, which explains why foo is not accessible in the constructor

Comment: As an aside, in the second example, `create` should probably be attached to `function Thing` itself instead of the prototype of `Thing`. I think that's how most would think static functions work.

Comment: @noppa Correct, that's what I meant to say. Thanks for spotting.

Answer (score 2):

What you are expecting to happen (functions inheriting variable bindings from the functions that called them) is known as *dynamic* variable scope. On the other hand, Javascript has *static* (also known as *lexical*) variable scope, meaning that that variable bindings are based purely on what functions are nested inside each other in the source code. This is a good thing because it means you don't need to think about how your functions get called to figure out what their variables mean. You only need to look at how the functions are written.

For more on the difference between lexical and dynamic scoping, the wikipedia article seems to be a good place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Lexical_scoping